# Cannot commit a network folder when using an external git folder on another network folder

Tags: windows, git

In this case I use git as a simple versioning backup-tool.
On a server I store some data which is backed up to a shared folder on a NAS.
Since the storage is limited on the server, I want only a repository on the NAS and not on the server itself. Speed is of no concern since there is not much data added and no comparison is needed (mainly images).

I commit from my personal PC.

I have the following setup:

On the server I have a network folder mapped as "V:" on my PC.
I have a git repository at top level (i.e. `V:\`) which stores its data on another network share via a ".git" file:

```
gitdir: \\172.16.2.100/folder/repository.git
```

When trying to commit with tortoise git I get an error like this:

```
fatal: Unable to create 'V:/..///172.16.2.100/folder/repository.git/index.lock': No such file or directory
```

When using the git shell:

```
$ git version
git version 1.8.4.msysgit.0

$ git add .
fatal: Unable to create 'v:/..///172.16.2.100/folder/repository.git/index.lock': No such file or directory
```

Specifying the git dir like this doesn't help either:

```
$ git --git-dir=//172.16.2.100/folder/repository.git add .
fatal: Unable to create 'v:/..///172.16.2.100/folder/repository.git/index.lock': No such file or directory


$ git --git-dir=\\172.16.2.100/folder/repository.git add .
fatal: Not a git repository: '\172.16.2.100/folder/repository.git'

$ git --git-dir=\\\\172.16.2.100/folder/repository.git add .
fatal: Unable to create 'v:/../\\172.16.2.100/folder/repository.git/index.lock': No such file or directory
```

Additionally adding a `--work-dir=.` option doesn't help either.

I already have some commits in the repository, but these were added when using a previous version of git. So this setup has worked once.

I also tried to move the data from `V:\` to `V:\someFolder`. This only results in one additional `/..` which produces the same error.

Commands like `git log` work:

```
$ git log -1
commit bd1688918313c72c65392a3581718a27b1d770b5
Author: xxxxxxxxxx <xxxxxxxxxxxxx>
Date:   Tue Oct 29 13:32:57 2013 +0100

    * backup only
```

How can I fix this besides trying to install a previous version of git?

UPDATES:

- also replaced the `--work-dir` option with `--work-tree` with no observable effect
- Also tried mapping the NAS to `Y` and replacing `\172.16.2.100/folder` with `Y:`.
  Same error with only the same replacement in the error message:

  ```
  fatal: Unable to create 'v:/../Y:/repository.git/index.lock': No such file or directory
  ```

Comment: I guess it should be "--work-tree" , not --work-dir, can you check once??

e.g, git --work-tree=/tmp/myproject status --short

Comment: @Shunya: You're right. But it didn't change the error message.

Comment: Your "V:\" is already mapped to "\\172.16.2.100\folder", so --gitdir should be "V:\repository.git".  (Totally untested answer)

Comment: @Shunya: This should be the same as omitting the `--gitdir` option. Also the same kind of error message.

Comment: From the recent error message : "fatal: Unable to create 'v:/../Y:/repository.git/index.lock':" , it appears the error is because of wrong mapping.  I suggest the following
1.  Remove your existing NAS mappings for git.
2.  Map "\\172.16.2.100\folder" to some drive, say "X"
3.  set git directory env variable "--gitdir" to "X:\repository.git"

Comment: @Shunya: I've already tried this. Similar error: `$ git --git-dir=Y:\repository.git add .` produces the error
`fatal: unable to access '../Y:repository.git/config': Invalid argument`

Comment: The slightly different command  ("/" instead of "\" ) `$ git --git-dir=Y:/imagebackup.git add . ` produces the error `
fatal: Unable to create 'v:/../Y:/imagebackup.git/index.lock': No such file or directory`